# Download only necessary NuGet packages

Tags: c#, nuget-package, nugetgallery, manage-nuget-packages

When I want to do my own NuGet package with custom authentication scheme, I need to download `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication` that contains `AuthenticationScheme` class. I need only this one class but together with this package there is downloaded 36 transitive packages. How can I reject these packages? Is it possible?

Comment: What makes you think that this package will function correctly without its transitive dependencies?

Comment: Because I really dont think that AuthenticationHandler uses DataProtection, Cryptography, FileProviders and others.

Comment: What makes you think that? Transitive dependencies exist for a reason.

Comment: I see it by `using`, imported namespaces. But in fact, I checked it in a class that only I need as ignorant. I rushed with this question, sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you take onboard a new dependency you implicitly takes on its transitive dependencies. If you start messing with it then code you want to depend on will not work. It is just the price you pay for the dependency.